# What's wrong with this particular regular expression?

Tags: regex, validation, pattern-matching

I need to write a regular expression to validate the input in a form. I want to restrict the use of these characters: **\ / & < > "** . Everything else is allowed.

Examples of valid inputs are: `My Basket`, `Groceries`, `Fruits`, `£$%`, and `+=`.

Examples of invalid inputs are: `A&B`, `A > B`, `2 / 3`, and `A<>C`.

Below is the code I'm using which is not working properly, because it returns as valid some inputs than actually are invalids.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter text: ");
            String inputText = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("\nThe input is " + (isValidInput(inputText) ? "valid" : "invalid"));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidInput(String inputText) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^/\\\\/&<>\"]");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(inputText);

        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply use `String.matches()` here?

Comment: @devnull yes, I can but that's not what worries me, my problem is related with the regular expression itself.

Comment: With regex questions you need to add a tag for the language you are using. (Looks like Java?)

Comment: For future reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding `[^/\\\\&<>\"]` will only check that at least one of the character isn't a forbidden one.

If you want to check that *the whole string* is made of allowed characters, you have to anchor the regex:

```
Pattern.compile("^[^/\\\\&<>\"]*$").matcher(inputText).find();
```

With `^$` matching the beginning and end of the string.

Or, as pointed out by @devnull, you can use `String.matches` wihch anchors the regex by default:

```
inputText.matches("[^/\\\\&<>\"]*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your find will succeed if it finds any character that is not in your list, regardless of the presence of such characters in other parts of the string. Try:

```
"^[^/\\\\/&<>\"]*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses negative lookahead to find if the string contains  `\ / & < > "`

```
if (subjectString.matches("^(?!.*[\\\\/&<>\"]).*$")) {
        // VALID STRING
    } else {
        // INVALID STRING
    }
```